# Increment counter to 1000 when 1000 parallel request are hitting a REST API

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, spring-mvc

Question Set in series .

1. Create a RESTful API using Spring MVC architecture that increments this number.
2. Use JMeter to call this API with 1000 users so that a lot of parallel requests are sent to the server to increment the number.
3. Now set the initial value of Number to 0.
4. After the execution of Jmeter, the value of the number in the database shall be 1000.

This is my scenario. I am unable to decide what to use to handle this. My expectations or solutions for this.

- Will spring automatically handle this?
- Or do I need to make the counter method synchronized?
- Or do I have to make 1000 threads and have to make them wait for 
  execution of previous thread?

Comment: Show your efforts before asking question

Answer (score 0):

You could use a static [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

```
private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

public static int incrementCounter() {
    return counter.incrementAndGet();
}
```

An `AtomicInteger` does not need synchronization.